# connecting snippets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pipe

I have the below data frame and currently I am just manually doing "Ctrl+Enter" chunk by chunk from "MD"(download the updated data) to "D3"(display the data in a data frame), every time when I need to refresh the data.

```
library(pedquant)

#download price data & create the data frame

MD<-md_stock(c("600028","601857","00386.HK","00857.HK"),type='real')
D1<-data.frame("A-shares"=MD$symbol[1:2],
              "A-price"=MD$close[1:2],
              "A-Trade Time"=MD$time[1:2],
              "Vol"=MD$volume[1:2],
              "Chg"=MD$close[1:2]-MD$close_prev[1:2],
              )
D2<-data.frame("H-shares"=MD$symbol[3:4],
               "H-price"=MD$close[3:4],
               "H-Trade Time"=MD$time[3:4],
              "Vol"=MD$volume[3:4],
              "Chg"=MD$close[3:4]-MD$close_prev[3:4]
              )

D3<-cbind(D1,D2)
D3$Spread=D3[,2]-D3[,7]
D3

> D3
   A.shares A.price        A.Trade.Time      Vol   Chg H.shares H.price        H.Trade.Time       Vol   Chg Spread
1 600028.SS    4.31 2022-11-17 15:59:07 72950000  0.01 00386.HK    3.42 2022-11-17 16:08:33 121027631 -0.03   0.89
2 601857.SS    5.04 2022-11-17 15:59:08 78534500 -0.02 00857.HK    3.38 2022-11-17 16:08:34  77039379 -0.04   1.66
```

I would like to ask, in this case, is there any operator I can use to connect all chunks together, so I do not have to manually update every chunk? I tried '%>%' but does not seem to be working. Million thanks for your help.

Comment: You can highlight all the parts you want to run and then it ctrl-enter. They way you've written these commands are not pipeable. You could write a function that you could call in one line to do all these steps. In RStudio there are options to Re-Run Previous Lines or Run Region (see the Code drop down menu)

Comment: thanks @MrFlick, may I also ask what kind of requirements or factors that my  commands would need to make it pipeable ?